# Microstack Accelerometer not working. I2C issue?

Tags: raspbian, python, i2c

I just received a Microstack Accelerometer about a week and a half ago. I put the Accelerometer onto the Microstack Baseboard and followed all of the instructions that were provided [here](http://www.microstack.org.uk/assets/accel/FormattedAccelgettingstarted.pdf).

When I go to run the example in the command line: `python3 /usr/share/doc/python3­microstacknode/examples/accelcat.py`, it gives this error:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ python3 /usr/share/doc/python3-microstacknode/examples/accelcat.py  Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "/usr/share/doc/python3-microstacknode/examples/accelcat.py", line 8, in <module> 
    accelerometer.init() 
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/microstacknode/accelerometer/mma8452q.py", line 115, in init 
    self.standby() 
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/microstacknode/accelerometer/mma8452q.py", line 127, in standby 
    self.ctrl_reg1.value &= 0xff ^ CTRL_REG1_SET_ACTIVE 
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/microstacknode/accelerometer/mma8452q.py", line 213, in value 
    v)) 
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/microstackcommon/i2c.py", line 85, in transaction 
    ioctl(self.fd, I2C_RDWR, ioctl_arg)  IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

When I run `sudo i2cdetect -y 1` I get a blank table.

Here is my setup:
[image]

Why is this not working?

The documentation doesn't really help you if there was an error.

I am a pretty big noob when it comes to Rasbian, so the more dumbed down the answer, the better.

Any help would be nice!

Comment: If you get a blank table the I2C device is not connected properly.  Could you post a photo of your set up and detail the connections you have made between the Pi and the I2C device?

Comment: I can't see that much can go wrong if it's simply a case of plugging a board over the Pi.  No chance of getting anything the wrong way round?  Until it is visible to i2cdetect there is no point in running other software.

Comment: I have the same problem, a Pi 2 Model B and the Microstack Baseboard and the Acceleratorometer and GPS neither of which work. Like you my i2C table is blank but the drivers are loaded. I have two baseboards and get the same with either so really scratching. Has anyone got this to work?? I have a call in with Element14 but so far they have not got back to me. Thanks, Scott.

Comment: try disabling file_tree in raspi-config -> advanced. That enabled me to see my devices in i2c, but I still haven got them working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problems. I'd given up when persistence got the better of me and I came across this: https://github.com/microstack-IoT/python3-microstacknode/issues/1

From your photo I'd say you are one of the 'couple' of boards made without the connection between pin 2 and 3 on JP1.

[image: Missing connection.]

You need to bridge this connection (I stuck a bent staple in the holes, but soldering may be better)!